Does Lite IDE works with Qt 6
I was trying to install the Lite IDE as per the Doc: https://github.com/visualfc/liteide/blob/master/liteidex/deploy/welcome/en/install.md
Go version: go1.22.3
Brew is installing 6.7 version of Qt by default, and on executing ./build_macos_qt5.sh it is failing with below error:
In file included from .moc/release-shared/moc_liteapi.cpp:9:
.moc/release-shared/../../../../../../liteidex/src/api/liteapi/liteapi.h:653:70: error: no member named 'AllDockWidgetFeatures' in 'QDockWidget'; did you mean 'Qt::AllDockWidgetAreas'?
                         QDockWidget::DockWidgetFeatures  features = QDockWidget::AllDockWidgetFeatures) = 0;
                                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                     Qt::AllDockWidgetAreas
/opt/homebrew/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qnamespace.h:1202:9: note: 'Qt::AllDockWidgetAreas' declared here
        AllDockWidgetAreas = DockWidgetArea_Mask,
        ^
In file included from .moc/release-shared/moc_liteapi.cpp:9:
.moc/release-shared/../../../../../../liteidex/src/api/liteapi/liteapi.h:653:59: error: no viable conversion from 'Qt::DockWidgetArea' to 'QDockWidget::DockWidgetFeatures' (aka 'QFlags<DockWidgetFeature>')
                         QDockWidget::DockWidgetFeatures  features = QDockWidget::AllDockWidgetFeatures) = 0;
                                                          ^          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/homebrew/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qflags.h:52:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'Qt::DockWidgetArea' to 'const QFlags<QDockWidget::DockWidgetFeature> &' for 1st argument
class QFlags
      ^
/opt/homebrew/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qflags.h:52:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'Qt::DockWidgetArea' to 'QFlags<QDockWidget::DockWidgetFeature> &&' for 1st argument
/opt/homebrew/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qflags.h:74:33: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'Qt::DockWidgetArea' to 'QDockWidget::DockWidgetFeature' for 1st argument
    constexpr inline Q_IMPLICIT QFlags(Enum flags) noexcept : i(Int(flags)) {}
                                ^
/opt/homebrew/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qflags.h:75:33: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'Qt::DockWidgetArea' to 'QFlag' for 1st argument
    constexpr inline Q_IMPLICIT QFlags(QFlag flag) noexcept : i(flag) {}
                                ^
/opt/homebrew/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qflags.h:77:22: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'Qt::DockWidgetArea' to 'std::initializer_list<DockWidgetFeature>' for 1st argument
    constexpr inline QFlags(std::initializer_list<Enum> flags) noexcept
                     ^
.moc/release-shared/../../../../../../liteidex/src/api/liteapi/liteapi.h:653:59: note: passing argument to parameter 'features' here
                         QDockWidget::DockWidgetFeatures  features = QDockWidget::AllDockWidgetFeatures) = 0;
                                                          ^
2 errors generated.
make[3]: *** [.obj/release-shared/moc_liteapi.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [sub-liteapi-make_first-ordered] Error 2
make[1]: *** [sub-api-make_first-ordered] Error 2
make: *** [sub-src-make_first-ordered] Error 2
error, make fail

Is there any workaround for this issue, thanks in advance.
I also tried with brew qt@5, but then i start getting this issue:
.moc/release-shared/moc_liteapi.cpp:13:10: fatal error: 'QtCore/qtmochelpers.h' file not found
#include <QtCore/qtmochelpers.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.moc/release-shared/moc_liteapi.cpp:13:10: note: did not find header 'qtmochelpers.h' in framework 'QtCore' (loaded from '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.13_1/lib')
1 error generated.
make[3]: *** [.obj/release-shared/moc_liteapi.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [sub-liteapi-make_first-ordered] Error 2
make[1]: *** [sub-api-make_first-ordered] Error 2
make: *** [sub-src-make_first-ordered] Error 2
error, make fail


I mean - isn't the name of the script descriptive enough: build_macos_qt5.sh? Even the documenation says: "You will need to install Qt4/Qt5 in order to compile the source"
